# MS SQL Order BY Case

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a query with 3 columns (for sake of the example). One is `DATE` and one is `[Type]` and one is `PRODUCT`. I need to order the query by DATE but also by type in terms that name like `Buy`, `Transfer In` shows up first and then `Transfer Out` and `Sell`. The order of `[Type]` is very important for me since there is this case where I get `Sell` even before I see `Buy` for same product...

```
SELECT [PRODUCT], [DATE], [TYPE]
FROM table_name
ORDER BY [DATE] ASC
```

Is there a way to order it like that. The names aren't necessary alphabetical order.

For example:

Washer , 20100506, Sell
  Washer , 20100506, Buy

And i need that in order Buy, then Sell. But keep in mind that Buy and Sell are just examples and it won't be named like that so alphabetical sorting isn't reallly gonna help here. I would like to be able to define the order of Type if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a few you could put the logic in a case statement

```
SELECT [DATE], [TYPE]
FROM table_name
ORDER BY [DATE] ASC, 
   CASE WHEN [Type]  IN (`Buy`,'TransferIn') Then 0 Else 1 End ASC
```

Otherwise you may be better off creating a table, view, or TVF that maps types and sort orders that you can then join on.

Comment: Tested and it seems to work! Will test a bit more to see if i won't be hit by the bus with other cases ;) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this:

```
SELECT ProductID, Name FROM Production.Product
WHERE Name LIKE 'Lock Washer%'
ORDER BY ProductID ;
```

Or this:

```
SELECT ProductID, Name FROM Production.Product
WHERE Name LIKE 'Lock Washer%'
ORDER BY ProductID DESC;
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Don't think this will work for me. Updated my post to make sure it's a bit more commented on what i want.